# Difference between supertest's expect and then?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, es6-promise, supertest

When using `supertest` for testing async HTTP requests in JavaScript, what's the difference between these two snippets? Is one of them correct and the other one wrong?

`request('http://localhost:8080/').get('/api/people')
  .expect(res => res.body.should.have.length(5))`

vs.

`request('http://localhost:8080/').get('/api/people')
  .then(res => res.body.should.have.length(5))`

The only differences I could notice were:

- `expect` returns a `Test` object and, when test fails, prints a large stack trace
- `then` returns a `Promise` object and, when test fails,
  prints a small stack trace

Comment: I think just reporting. For the first option you will get 2 success assertions if everything runs fine. And for the second just one assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what test runner you're using will obviously affect the answer, but something like `Mocha` will allow you to return the `Promise` directly in your test and this will wait to be resolved before the test passes.

So if you having something like:

```
describe('Your test case', function () {

  it('will wait for promise to resolve', function () {
    return request('http://localhost:8080/').get('/api/people')
      .then(res => res.body.should.have.length(5))
  })

})
```

Whereas in the other instance you really *should* use a done callback as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest docs.