# Why do my supertest tests fail intermittently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I have a web app with about 4000 route tests. I am now seeing regular failures, with no consistency: 1 failure, 3 failures, pass - 2 examples:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/markry/workspace/personal/supertest-example/tests.spec.js)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

A working example can be run using: https://github.com/joshmatz/supertest-example and wrapping a for loop around the test.

```
for (step = 0; step < 5000; step++) {
  it('should have return version number', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .get('/api')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(res.body.version).to.be.ok;
        expect(res.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
}
```

Is this some sort of host limitation? How can I debug this?

Thanks :)

----- UPDATE -----

If I use SuperAgent(https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) I get 100% reliability with below:

```
for (step = 0; step < 5000; step++) {
  it('should have return version number', function(done) {
   request
   .get('http://localhost:3000/api')
   .end(function(err, res) {
      expect(res.body.version).to.be.ok;
      expect(res.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
      done();
    });
  });
}
```

Also added this snippet to server.js:

```
// take the port or set it to 3000
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log('port=' + port)
// start the server
app.listen(port);
```

I'm changing my tests to use SuperAgent :)

Comment: Why not use `then`?

Comment: Just tried (spoiler: no joy) on a VM running Ubuntu 16.04. Cloned your linked `supertest-example`, then `npm i`, then rewrote the main test to run 5k times the version number test, then `npm i mocha`, then `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha '**/*.spec.js'`. Result: `5008 passing (11s)`. Ran several times, tried first using node 8.10 (my default), then switched (using `nvm`) to 4.2.2 as per your `package.json` - however `nvm` reports `npm 2.14.7` instead of specified 3.6.0, but I doubt it's relevant here.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna: is it relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919242/difference-between-supertests-expect-and-then

Comment: @StockOverflaw weird, I am running directly on host. I do see this behaviour elsewhere too. But I will try to replicate in a VM.